# There is an extra <a> tag added between <a> tags list in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a menu consisting of a tags with 'display:block' and it seems that between every two a tags, another a tag is inserted between them - in Chrome at least. I find this behavior most odd. What can I do to get rid of them?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.monespace_menu-items a {
text-decoration: none;
padding-top:5px;
width:100%;
color:#D3D3D3;
margin:0;
display:block;
padding-left:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
.monespace_menu-items a:hover {
color:white;
background-color:black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="monespace_menu-items">
    <a href="#">href 1<a/>
    <a href="#">href 2<a/>
    <a href="#">href 3<a/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75ybtuv1/2/

Any input is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo, you should close your tag like this `</a>` not like this `<a/>`

Answer (score 2):

**your tag like this `</a>` not like this `<a/>`**

```
      <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        .monespace_menu-items a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-top:5px;
        width:100%;
        color:#D3D3D3;
        margin:0;
        display:block;
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        }
        .monespace_menu-items a:hover {
        color:white;
        background-color:black;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
    
        <div class="monespace_menu-items">
      <a href="#">href 1</a>
      <a href="#">href 2</a>
      <a href="#">href 3</a>
        </div>
    
        </body>
        </html>
```